# Removing Database from AlwaysOn Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have a 2-node SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Group.  When I execute this T-SQL command on the Primary server:

```
USE master 
go 
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP MyAG REMOVE DATABASE TestDB
```

it removes the `TestDB` from the Availability Group.  Everything looks fine on the Primary server.  However, on the Secondary replica, the `TestDB` has the status of "Restoring ..." next to it.   The database is inaccessible.  The status remains "Restoring..." for a while.  Looks like the only thing I could do is to drop it, which I did.

My question is: after I remove the DB from MyAG, what do I need to do to make the `TestDB` available for use again on the secondary replica?

Comment: Have a look at MS-Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/remove-a-secondary-replica-from-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply run

```
RESTORE DATABASE TestDB WITH RECOVERY
```

on the secondary.

Comment: Hi Tony, thank you.  It worked.